# Faye and Nodejs Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, faye

Hi currently I'm trying to do a notification feature on a webapp and I decided to use Faye in order to make them live notifications. Now the feature works fine on my local computer, but when somebody else tries to connect to my network, they get a connection refused and faye doesn't work.

Current code working on my local machine:

```
    var http = require('http');
    var faye = require('faye');

    var server = http.createServer();
    var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye', timeout: 45});

    bayeux.attach(server);
    server.listen(8000);
```

I managed to read some other questions related to this issue, and people said to make the server listen to all interfaces by adding: '0.0.0.0' to the server.listen call. When I do this it even stops working on my local machine. Any help will be appreciated!, Nodejs is not the only server running on my machine but the port is open so thats not an issue. I get a get failed request towards the faye message request.

Comment: you want other people to connect to YOUR machine?

Comment: why not using websockets ?

Comment: jaja i might have said that wrong tan, guys enter the app on my machine through localhost but the faye just refuses to establish connection with them!